# Jquery only toggle 1 element our of 7

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I have this html repeat 8 times on a page:

```
<div class="call-to-action">
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <a class="info-button" href="#">more info</a>
    <div class="more-info">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to use this jQuery:

```
$('.info-button').click(function() {
    $('.more-info').toggle();
});
```

The problem is, whenever I click one of the .info-button all of the .more-info divs show themselves at the same time. How do I get it to show only the .more-info div in the same container (.call-to-action) div?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `more-info` element you want to toggle is the next sibling element of the clicked `info-button` so use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find that element

```
$('.info-button').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.more-info').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.info-button').click(function() {
    $('.more-info').hide(); //hide any that are already open (optional).
    $(this).next('.more-info').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.info-button').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle(); // toggles the next element which is <div class="more-info">
});
```